# Samples/tutorial for DRM framework in Android

Tags: android, drm, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Android 4.0 brings drm framework to smartphones. I'm interested to write a code that plays video protected by the DRM, but can't find enough information.

1. Are there any tutorials on using the DRM framework? Sample code?
2. How to set up an environment - the server side that creates the content and licenses?
3. Are there any DRM protected videos in the Internet that I can use for testing?
4. The plugin framework claims extensibility, but I can't find neither plugin AI definitions, nor description how to create/add a custom plugin

Comment: DRM added on API 11 (android 3.0) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/DrmManagerClient.html

Comment: Did you find any sample?!

Comment: for future readers, I recently wrote a post about drm here http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/ it covers widevine which is supported by andriod 4.3+

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT**: An example pass-through DRM plugin is now available in AOSP under **frameworks/base/drm/libdrmframework/plugins/passthru/**

---

> Are there any tutorials on using the DRM framework? Sample code?

Not yet, unfortunately. The only public documentation on this is at the [android.drm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html) package summary docs.

> How to set up an environment - the server side that creates the content and licenses?

This is specific to the DRM provider.

> Are there any DRM protected videos in the Internet that I can use for testing?

This too is specific to the DRM provider.

> The plugin framework claims extensibility, but I can't find neither plugin AI definitions, nor description how to create/add a custom plugin

I think this will become more clear once the source code is released, but for now there isn't any further info on this unfortunately.

Comment: Any clue where this example was moved too? frameworks/base/drm only has a java and jni folder now.

Comment: @schwiz, a little late, but this was moved to `/frameworks/av/drm`

Answer (score 0):

Probably one way to check is using the demo app in the [Exoplayer library](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos).
The demo player uses some [test content](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/assets/media.exolist.json) for widevine and playready. So you can refer to the APIs being used.