# How to use android DRM framework in application

Tags: android, security, drm, android-drm

I am developing an android application based on DRM.I have searched alot but did not get any sample/example that explain how to implement DRM in our application.

So please share some example/sample code that explain implementation of DRM framework.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915763/samples-tutorial-for-drm-framework-in-android

Comment: i have checked that ,but did not get any useful example for drm